# insert datetime error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have problem when inserting a date to my database
Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO users (f_name, s_name, t_name,family_name, age, national_id, 
telephone, mobile,  address, job_name, company_code, start_date, end_date)
VALUES (N'" + fname + "',N'" + sname + "',N'" + tname + "',N'" + famiy_name + 
        "',N'" + age + "',N'" + national_id + "',N'" + telephone + 
        "',N'" + mobile + "',N'" + address + "',N'" + job_name + "',N'" + 
        company_code + "'," + start_date + "," + end_date + ")";
```

Note the capital letter "N" before entries to be able to insert Arabic words

The error message:

> Incorrect syntax near '12'.

Although the date format from text visualizer is

> 05/11/2010 12:00:00 AM

I use VS2010 with DB sql express 2008

Comment: Do you need the "N" to insert numeric values as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameters instead of concatenation to build your query:

```
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO users (f_name, s_name, ...) VALUES (@f_name, @s_name, ...)")) {

    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", f_name);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_name", s_name);
    //...

    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery())
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks otiel i allready change to use parameters instead of concatenation , and the problem solved

Answer (score 3):

**Why this is happening**: It looks like you forgot to delimit your dates with single quotes.

**What you should do**: use [parameterized queries](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/ad526a4b-61af-4f99-b6f1-2c0752006541) instead and you don't have to worry about delimiting or SQL injection (Otiel's answer has a nice sample)